# .NET StarCraft 2 Replay Reader that is actively maintained?

Tags: .net, open-source, replay

Anyone know of a good SC2 Replay reader written in .NET and Open Sourced that they would recommend?  For that matter, one that is actively maintained?  (Admittedly, if the format doesn't change much then I don't see a reason that old code wouldn't still work).

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's https://github.com/ascendedguard/sc2replay-csharp

Comment: Ooh -- that might be the ticket.  Not enough google-ing on my part I think.  I'll have to test this out -- and if all is good accept this answer.  Bam.

Comment: It's written in .Net, is actively maintained, and is open source.  All three criterion specified in the question are met.  I'm only going to get credit if the project is *good enough*?  This hardly seems fair.

Comment: Nope -- if it works really.  I would say.  It turns out that I cloned the project, fired it up, and it has a bug.  It doesn't provided player, or game events.  I guess I didn't put in my original question "and works" though that should have been implied.  It's still a good find though -- I might be able to find the bug and contribute back.  (I hesitate to accept an answer without first making sure the code works is all -- been burned by that too many times.  Same goes for when a search produces promising results but none of them pan out).

Answer (score 0):

[sc2reader](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sc2reader), while in Python, meets your other criteria.