# Getting specific metrics from StarCraft 2 Replays

Tags: parsing, game-engine, replay, starcraftgym

I'm looking for a way to pull some metrics from a replay, but after doing some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361234/net-starcraft-2-replay-reader-that-is-actively-maintained) I think this might be more difficult than I originally thought.  From what I've found, the SC2 Replay is mostly events (and some info about the replay and players), those events by themselves don't provide the information I was hoping to pull, because the replay and the game engine are highly tied together (of course).

So, I'm wondering if anyone has a solution on how to pull metrics from a replay?  I was looking for these kinds of things:

- Current Army Value
- Current Floating Resources
- Current Building Production
- ...

Basically every 30seconds or something.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for Starcraft2 -- makes me lol every time?  Besides, I picture Vader hanging out in the cantina BSing about SC2 too.

Answer (score 3):

ggtracker uses sc2reader to get something close to the current army value -- it computes the "active army" size.  active army is based on player selection actions.  a unit joins the "active army" the first time it is selected, and leaves the "active army" after the last time it is selected.

you may also be interested in the stats contained within the s2gs file, which are displayed in the post-game stats display.  for example it contains the army size graph and income graph data.  s2gs files can be parsed by sc2reader.  this teamliquid thread has more details about how you can obtain s2gs files: http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=330926.  basically, you can manually cause the s2gs files to appear on your computer by clicking in the SC2 client.